# Manipulate absolute and relative front-size in CSS

Tags: css, accessibility, font-size

What defines the algorithm behind absolute and relative font sizes?

For Example: `font-size: smaller` or `font-size: small`

I know that this relative/absolute font-size declaration makes the font smaller by a certain percentage, but what is defining this percentage, and how can I manipulate it?

*I'm aware that there are ways to achieve the same result in different ways. But I would love to use **this** in my CSS by having control over the final result.*

Couldn't find any explanation yet.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I know that this relative/absolute font-size declaration makes the font smaller by a certain percentage,  ...

No it doesn't. The ratios differ. See the table at https://www.w3.org/TR/css-fonts-4/#absolute-size-mapping. Browsers may tweak the values as they see fit, on a per font basis if necessary.

> how can I manipulate it?

You can't. Skip the named font sizes and just specify the pixel sizes, em/rem ratios or percentage values as you require them.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for.